# Will adding spans for star ratings inside the H1 tag affect SEO?

Tags: seo, html, h1

If I add these `span` elements inside the `h1` element, will it affect my SEO?

```html
<h1>PRODUCT 123456789
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span></h1>
```

Comment: Given your example, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to assume that it affects search engines in any way. These are just empty, meaningless elements, as far as the HTML is concerned.

If you care about semantic HTML, you might want to use different markup, though. The star rating value is part of the content, so it shouldn’t be added via CSS. The `meter` element can be used for it. It conveys the rating value in a machine-readable way.

```html
<h1>
  PRODUCT 123456789 
  <meter value="3" min="0" max="5">★★★☆☆</meter>
</h1>
```

(Adding the stars as actual content will of course affect search engines, as they now have content that could be displayed e.g. in their result snippets. You could also use a CSS-only way with `meter`; it would still be better than using `span`, as text browsers, accessibility tools etc. have the chance to convey the rating.)